# What is the relation between speed, angular velocity and radius?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

How are angular velocity, speed and radius related to each other?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the vector cross product to find the velocity vector $\vec{v}$ that results from the rotational velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$ at a location $\vec{r}$ relative to the rotation axis.

$$ \vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r} $$

On a plane the above becomes

$$ \pmatrix{v_x \\ v_y} = \pmatrix{-\omega\, y \\ \omega\, x} $$

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for this $$v^2 = \dot r^2 + r^2 \dot \phi^2 ~.$$